# Detect if reportValidity() is currently showing the validityMessage on a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, safari, client-side-validation

Calling `reportValidity()` on in *invalid* field causes the validation message to show in a browser-dependent way.

However, calling `reportValidity()` **again** causes the validation message to disappear on Safari but not Firefox. Repeatedly calling it causes it to toggle, making cross-browser validation difficult.

In my specific case, I want to show the validation message on form submit and on input focus. When you submit the form and it is invalid, the event triggers `reportValidity()` on the form. However, this will focus the input that is invalid, triggering the `reportValidity()` again from my focus event, hiding the message that was just shown.

Is there a way to reliably show the message when you don't know if it's already showing? Does the browser provide an interface for detecting if the validity message is showing?

Example:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("invalid")
input.addEventListener("focus", () => input.reportValidity())
const form = document.getElementById("form")
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => { e.preventDefault(); form.reportValidity() })
```

```html
<form action="#" id="form">
  <input type="number" max="5" value="10" name="invalid" id="invalid" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="submit" value="validate">
</form>
```

On Safari, this example will cause the validation message to hide when submitting the form. This is not the desired behavior.

Comment: Toggling seems like a Safari bug. I don't think there's any way to get the reporting status, unless there's something Safari-specific.

Comment: I tried your code in Safari. It's not toggling the message each time `reportValidity()` is called. It shows the message, then removes it while you're editing the input.

Comment: @Barmar It still does it for me in both mobile and desktop safari. In the snippet it will auto-hide the message as soon as it shows because the focus even toggles it off. You can likewise use setTimeout to call reportValidity every second and it toggles back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should file a bug at https://bugs.webkit.org/.

The issue seems to be caused by the fact the browser will itself focus the `<input>` from the call to `reportValidity()`, causing that toggling. So one way to handle it is to listen to the [`invalid` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/invalid_event) and prevent it when it's already been called in the same task. Luckily, that event is fired synchronously and is cancellable, so it's relatively easy to handle it.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("invalid")
input.addEventListener("focus", () => input.reportValidity())
const form = document.getElementById("form")
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => { e.preventDefault(); form.reportValidity() })
let reporting = false;
input.addEventListener("invalid", (e) => {
  // debounce the reportValidity call
  if (reporting) { e.preventDefault(); }
  reporting = true;
  setTimeout(() => reporting = false);
});
input.addEventListener("focusin", (e) => {
  input.reportValidity();
});
```

```html
<form action="#" id="form">
  <input type="number" max="5" value="10" name="invalid" id="invalid" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="submit" value="validate">
</form>
```

Comment: Great solution. I tried handling the invalid event but didn’t think of a good way to use it. This works for me in mobile safari.